# Shell-sort algorithm variations in Java

Tags: java, sorting, shellsort

Is there a way to calculate the starting point of a for loop and the adjustments to it.  The original loop has these conditions

`for( int gap = a.length / 2; gap > 0; gap /= 2 )`

I adjusted it to set the conditions of the Hibbard's Shell Sort and got this

`for( int gap = (int) Math.pow(2, a.length); gap > 0; gap /= 2 )`

It works slightly better and might even be right, but I want to work with the more advanced shell sorts from here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort#Gap_sequences

How could I turn  (3^k - 1)/2 not greater than the ceiling of n/3 into a for loop condition?

Comment: Your question seems simple. Where are you struggling to convert these values? You seem aware of `Math.pow`. You're aware of `Math.ceil()` correct? Have you tried something that isn't quite working right?

Comment: using a ceiling just fixed one of them.  My problem is, unless I know where I'm supposed to start, I have no idea what to make of the for loop though for the more advanced onces.

Comment: I don't know what k in that equation is supposed to be actually.  Probably why I'm in trouble here.

Comment: (3^k - 1)/2 is the formula to give you the gap sequence for the first gap k = 1 for the second gap k = 2 giving you the values in get concrete gap column.

Answer (score 3):

The "k" value is the element of the sequence.  So your for loop would probably look something like:

```
    for (int k = 0; (Math.pow(3, k) - 1) / 2 <= Math.ceil(n / 3); k++) {
        int gap = (int) ((Math.pow(3, k) - 1) / 2);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( int gap = 1; gap < ((a.length + 2)/3); gap = (((((gap *2)+1)*3)-1)/2))
```